# VPN and SSH overseas

Tags: penetration-test, man-in-the-middle, ssh, vpn, tunneling

I stopped penetration testing and studying network security, for the most part, when the "NSA Playset" was released years ago. Thus, I have an IT question to impose upon you.

I will be traveling overseas and I will need to access a website and a server securely. If I connect to, say a hotel wifi in Thailand, can the SSH be sniffed and compromised? I have never read anything about stripping security from SSH so this is my main concern.

SSLstrip can compromise web traffic, thus I will certainly need a VPN. Should I also be using a private Sock proxy? Is there a precaution I can take before connecting to hotel wifi?

I feel I only need a VPN, but using wifi at a hotel in another country is really off-putting to me. Someone could potentially be snipping all traffic on known ports all ready and using some mechanism unknown to me to filter my traffic.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time thus far!

_Evan

Comment: A lot of hotel wifi only provides limited access - port 80 and 443 and even then the traffic is proxied. Using a tunnelled connection (ssh is fine for the tunnel) to an external host on port 443 should provide easy, secure access but you need to ensure this is the default route. SOCKs is just an added complication

Answer (score 1):

For the SSH part, as long as you will have the server public key stored in the `known_hosts` of your computer (or way to safely verify the fingerprint), the connection between your client and server can not be intercepted, modified nor compromised in any other way (given you are you using SSH2 protocol with current algorithms and keys of reasonable size).

You can use also SOCKS proxy over SSH, but full-featured VPN is probably a better way of doing that. Once again, VPN provides a way to authenticate the server to the client (certificate?) so once you will be connecting to the server, but I am not so well versed in this area so I will leave it for the others.